# How to access URL inside of a JSON API that leads to another JSON API, and display that information on a page in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have a property of 'inspection-link' that has a value of a URL that I'm pulling in from a JSON API.

```
"inspection-link": "https://qa.toromont.ca/ToromontCAT/ServiceHub/PublicInfo/ecomm/inspection?sku=N001|BFEN1868620151TLI45073",
```

Instead of simply displaying the "inspection-link" URL onto the pay, I need to be able to access the URL, and then display that information on the page.

The code I have below (`<p>{jsonDataProduct?.["inspection-link"]}</p>`) only displays the URL on the page in text, but of course I need to display that URL's data coming in from it's on JSON URL.

```
const PeriodicAnnualInspectionReport = ({
  lang,
  jsonDataProduct,
}: Props_PIReport) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-12">
          {}
          <h2>
            {outputEnFr(
              "Periodic Annual Inspection Report",
              "Rapport d'inspection annuel périodique",
              lang
            )}
          </h2>
          <p>{jsonDataProduct?.["inspection-link"]}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PeriodicAnnualInspectionReport;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then in the component mount using `useEffect` with empty array dependencies, and fetch the data from that URL, and set a state for it to update the UI, when data come.

```
const [data, setData] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
  if (jsonDataProduct) {
    fetch(jsonDataProduct["inspection-link"]).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setData(data));
  }
}, [])
```

Then you can output the data come from that json URL

Comment: Thanks for your help Mina! I'm doing a console.log(data) after the useEffect, but it's just showing [object Object]. How can I get it to display properly?

Comment: You are welcome, I see that the data of this URL is equal null.

Comment: Sorry! I just updated the JSON API URL to one the is currently live. Seems like the console.log is now returning [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Sorry, it should be `jsonDataProduct["inspection-link"]` instead of `jsonDataProduct.inspection-link` as `inspection-link` has a `-`

Comment: I just update the answer, please try again.

Comment: Also, this is a codesandbox with the data returned.
https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-williams-0zelh3